# Replace [user:name] in drupal 7 function _user_mail_text()

Tags: function, drupal-7, overriding

I want to replace [user:name] on function _user_mail_text() in Drupal 7 with textfield nickname of profile2 module. I can override this function on template.php or in my module or it's better to use another way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you want to override existing token when you can create your own ? 
Please read : https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488

Comment: because the owner of website wants to send by email not the default registration username but the nickname of profile2 module

Comment: C.  Max , Create your own token to achieve this , override registration template mail to use it as you want (https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-02-03/how-can-i-modify-the-email-to-admin-from-user)